# How to fill a letter (chess piece) with color

Tags: fonts, fontspec, chess, chessboard

[image]

I choosed a King from 'DejaVu Sans'. 
Is there a way to *fill* the a chess piece with white?

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\newcommand\Kw{\char"2654}% ♔
\newcommand\Kb{\char"265A}% ♚

\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{document}

\Huge\Kw {\color{white}\Huge\Kw}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX doesn't know the shape of a character, only the bounding box... you can still draw something (either manually figure out the coordinate in TeX, or use some external program to process the font)

Answer (score 6):

You can fake it by putting the black king behind the white king:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\newcommand\Kw{\char"2654}% ♔
\newcommand\Kb{\char"265A}% ♚

\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{document}

\Huge\Kw {\color{white}\Huge\rlap{\Kb}\Kw} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, '\rlap'.   Then I think I am looking for `{\Huge{\color{white}\rlap{\Kb}}{\Kw}} `

Comment: Is the overlapping even needed? It looks like the black king alone would get the same effect.

Comment: @DanielWagner if both are white probably, but with overlapping you can use two colors.